# how to pass arrays as parameters in constructor? c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameters, constructor

I am trying to make a constructor for class call, in which 4 arrays are passed as parameters. I've tried using `*,&`, and the array itself; however when I assign the values in the parameters to the variables in the class, I get this error :

```
 call.cpp: In constructor ‘call::call(int*, int*, char*, char*)’:
 call.cpp:4:15: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int*’ to ‘int [8]’
 call.cpp:5:16: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int*’ to ‘int [8]’
 call.cpp:6:16: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [14]’
 call.cpp:7:16: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [14]’
```

I would appreciate your help in finding my error and helping me correct it. 
here is my code:

### .h file

```
#ifndef call_h
#define call_h
class call{
private:
    int FROMNU[8]; 
    int DESTNUM[8];
    char INITIME[14]; 
    char ENDTIME[14];

public:
    call(int *,int *,char *,char *);
};
#endif
```

### .cpp file

```
call:: call(int FROMNU[8],int DESTNUM[8],char INITIME[14],char ENDTIME[14]){
    this->FROMNU=FROMNU;
    this->DESTNUM=DESTNUM;
    this->INITIME=INITIME;
    this->ENDTIME=ENDTIME;
}
```

Comment: Replace the arrays by `std::array` or `std::tr1::array` if you don't have C++11 support (or altenratively, `boost::array`)

Comment: Arrays are not the same thing as pointers, although in many cases they are demoted to pointers. For your use case, consider `std::array` instead of `[]` arrays.

Comment: You know variables can be lowercase, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raw arrays are non-assignable and generally difficult to handle. But you can put an array inside a `struct`, and assign or initialize that. Essentially that's what `std::array` is.

E.g. you can do

```
typedef std::array<int, 8>   num_t;
typedef std::array<char, 14> time_t;

class call_t
{
private:
    num_t    from_;
    num_t    dest_;
    time_t   init_;
    time_t   end_;

public:
    call_t(
        num_t const&     from,
        num_t const&     dest,
        time_t const&    init,
        time_t const&    end
        )
        : from_t( from ), dest_( dest ), init_( init ), end_( end )
    {}
};
```

But this still lacks some essential abstraction, so it's merely a *technical* solution.

To improve things, consider what e.g. `num_t` really is. Is it, perhaps, a telephone number? Then model it as such.

Consider also using standard library containers `std::vector` and, for the arrays of `char`, `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

**Passing a raw array as an argument is possible in C++.**

Consider the following code:

```
template<size_t array_size>
void f(char (&a)[array_size])
{
    size_t size_of_a = sizeof(a); // size_of_a is 8
}

int main()
{
    char a[8];
    f(a);
}
```

Comment: You're using C++11's `auto` in your code sample. Who in their right mind would have access to C++11 and use *that* instead of `std::array`?

Comment: 'auto' is not essential here. I replaced it with explicit 'size_t'

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ you cannot assign arrays by doing `this->FROMNU=FROMNU;` thus your method wont work, and is one half of your error.

The other half is that you try to assign a pointer to the array. Even if you pass arrays to a function, they decay to pointers to the first element, despite what you say in the definition.